# Return results when search parameters is null i Zend Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I have multiple fields in search form.Every field could be empty.
I build query like this:

```
$search_title = trim($_POST["search_title"]);
$search_skill = trim($_POST["search_skill"]);
$search_company = trim($_POST["search_city"]);
$search_country_id = trim($_POST["search_county_id"]);

$hits = $index->find("title:$search_title and skill:$search_skill and city:$search_city and country_id:$country_id");
```

User can only fill title or skill or city etc. but if some field is empty i have no result.
I have result only if all fields filled and matched.
I wont results if only one field is filled,if is null ignore that field:

```
$hits = $index->find("title: and skill: and city: and country_id:$country_id");
```

Comment: Look at this similar question I answered earlier for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764950/mysql-updating-some-database-fields-without-overwriting-fields-not-changed/9765118#9765118

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost)) {
                //get filtered and valid values from search form.
                //filter the array for set values
                $data = array_filter($form->getValues());
                //extract key => vaules as $variable = values
                extract($data);
                 $query1 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
                 //test for variable isset and add term to query
                 if (isset($search_title)){
                     $query1->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($search_title, 'title'));
                 }
                 if (isset($search_skill)){
                     $query1->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($search_skill, 'skill'));
                 }
                 if (isset($search_city)){
                     $query1->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($search_city, 'city'));
                 }
                 if (isset($search_country_id)){
                     $query1->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($search_country_id, 'country_id'));
                 }
                 //This should give the AND you are looking for...I hope
                 $query= new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean(array($query1), array(TRUE));
                 //get result set from query
                 $hits = $index->find($query);
            }
        }
```

if you use the `StringTrim` filter in your forms you won't need to use the `trim()` function on your data. The $_POST array is dangerous with user supplied data, ZF provides the `getValues()` series of methods to provide data from the Request Object (POST and GET) the have had filters and validators you specify applied.
I used the `extract()` function in this instance because I used `getValues()` so the data has been filtered and validated. There are of course other valid ways to assign `key => value` pairs to variables. Use your favorite.

Comment: This query return all: search_title OR search_skill OR search_city etc. ,but I need search_title AND search_skill etc.